# splitting a large text file into smaller text files

Tags: c#, winforms, streamreader, streamwriter

I'm trying to split a text file based on then number of lines contains around 6M lines and each file should always end (last line) with a certain identifier.
What I tried:

```
    using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(inputfile))
    {
        int fileNumber = 0;
        string line = "";
        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            int count = 0;
            //identifier = sr.ReadLine().Substring(0,2);
            using (System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(inputfile + ++fileNumber + ".TXT"))
            {
                sw.AutoFlush = true;
                

                while (!sr.EndOfStream && ++count < 1233123)
                {
                    line = sr.ReadLine();
                    sw.WriteLine(line);
                }
       //having problems starting here not sure how to implement the other condition   == "JK"
                line = sr.ReadLine();
                if (count > 1233123 && line.Substring(0,2) == "JK")
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(line);
                }
                else
                {
                    while (!sr.EndOfStream && line.Substring(0,2) != "JK")
                    {
                        line = sr.ReadLine();
                        sw.WriteLine(line);
                    }
                }
               
            }
        }
    }
```

sample input  text is like:

> ```
> AAadsadasdasdasdfsdfsdfs
> Bbasfafasfasdfdsfsdfsdff
> CCsafsdfasdadfasdfasfsaf
> DDasdsfsdfsafdsadfsafasf
> JKdfgdsgdsfgsdfgsfgdfgdf
> AAfsdfsadfsdfsaadfadasda
> BBadfasdfasdfdsfasfasdas
> CCadasdsfasdfasfasfasfds
> DDsdfsdafasdfsdfdsfsdfsd
> EEsadfsfsasafasdfsdfsdfs
> FFasfasfadsdfdsadssfsdfs
> JKadsadasdasdadsadasdasa
> AAadasdasdasdasdasdasdas
> BBasdadadadasdasdasdasdd
> CCadasdasdasdasdasdasdad
> JKsafsdfsdfasfasdfdasfsa
> ```

Basically what I'm trying to achieve is have multiple text files that has at least 1233123 lines or more (i.e if line 1233123 does not have "JK" then continue writing to current file till it is found).

Comment: Good description of what you are trying to do. But what is the question? It is usually a good idea to include the example input, expected output and actual output.

Comment: hi! thank you for your response, basically I'm trying to split the text file into multiple files with 2 conditions, I know how to apply at least the first condition i.e based on line number count i.e ( I can generate multiple text files with x count lines) but having problems implementing the other condition i.e each txt file should have an ending line that contains "JK"

Comment: So [String.Contains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=net-5.0)?

Comment: I'm using substring since the so called identifier "JK" is always the first 2 char per line, my problem with this code is somehow I'm missing 1 or 2 lines per text file :/

Comment: ok so I've tried making a dummy data with around 60 -68 lines and what I noticed is once I hit the target line count it doesnt add/write that line i.e if my target lines is 10 per file it will skip the 10th line in the original file.

Comment: edited added a comment where I think I'm having problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While reading and writing files check if your condition, line number greater than `1233123` and line starting with `JK`, is true. In this case you can stop writing to the file fragment and continue with the next iteration of your most outer loop, which starts writing to the next file.

```
using (System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(inputfile + ++fileNumber + ".TXT"))
{
    sw.AutoFlush = true;                

    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        line = sr.ReadLine();
        sw.WriteLine(line);

        if(++count > 1233123 && line.Substring(0,2) == "JK")
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of line.Substring(0,2) you can use line.Startswith("JK") aswell

Comment: would that affect speed or is just the same o;

Comment: I don't know if it is faster or not, but in my opinion it is better to read and to understand what is going on. The String.StartsWith("text") method probably checks if string.Substring(0, text.Length) is equal to "text", so it is just a shortcut which implemetns Substring() anyway. Maybe someone can confirm.